# Data Link - Hostname/Ip Address dynamically grafana

Tags: grafana

I have a table panel where I’m providing a data link for a column.
I want my current grafana hostname/ip adrress to be part of the link what I’m giving .

example : https://my-host-name/home/ 4…
Here my-host-name is my ip adress which I want from the current browser.
Let say my current browser url is https:/100.120.111.98/grafana, then my data link should be [https://100.120.111.98/home/…](https://100.120.111.98/home/%E2%80%A6)
Is it possible to take a browser hostname in data link

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking within one Grafana instance, you can simply leave out the domain name and use `/home/...` as link.